# How can I manually change the mouse/pointer speed?

Tags: mouse

I have an Apple Magic Mouse, and it's almost unusable since the sensitivity is too high. Yet in the Mouse/Touchpad settings, the pointer speed is set to the slowest possible setting. Is there a way to manually change this setting so that it's much slower than the slowest setting?

Answer (score 22):

The easiest way of doing this is `xset m`. The general format is:

```
xset m ACCELERATION THRESHOLD
```

> where ACCELERATION defines how many times faster the cursor will move than the default speed, when the cursor moves more than THRESHOLD pixels in a short time. ACCELERATION can be a fraction, so if you want to slow down the mouse you can use 1/2, and if 3 is slightly too fast, but 2 is too slow, you can use 5/2, etc.

For example:

```
xset m 1/2 4
```

To get the current values, use:

```
xset q | grep -A 1 Pointer
```

For more information, see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration#Using_xset).

Comment: Great! How to make this change permanent?

Comment: @guettli depends on what you are doing, how you are connecting to the machine etc, but usually, just adding `xset m 1/2 4` to your `.bashrc` will be enough. If not, or if you sometimes connect non-graphically, you might want to post a new question about that.